# how to convert input binary to text python

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary, numbers, decimal

I'm new to Python Programming and I made a simple Python program about converting text to binary numbers, now i'm adding a simple code for converting them back from binary to text (correct the code below if there is wrong).

```
message = (input("Enter Text/Binary to Translate: ")

binList = {
   '01100001': 'a', 
   '01100010': 'b', 
   # to Z 
} 

BinT = "".join([binList[message] for message in letter])

print(BinT)
```

Answer (score 3):

You should not use a lookup dict for this.  To convert a binary string to an ascii character, use built-in functions [`chr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#chr) and [`int`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) respectively:

```
>>> chr(int('01100001', 2))
'a'
```

To go the other way, use built-in functions [`format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#format) and [`ord`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord) respectively:

```
>>> format(ord('a'), '08b')
'01100001'
```

Comment: What I mean is that if I put a binary value in the program, then it'll convert to as a Text. Do you know other ways of fixing this?

Answer (score 0):

```
message = raw_input("Enter Text/Binary to Translate: ").split(' ')

binList = {
    '01100001': 'a',
    '01100010': 'b',
    # to Z
}

BinT = "".join( [binList[letter] for letter in message])

print(BinT)
```

Comment: You should elaborate, not just fix his code. Explain what is going wrong.